# Javascript object with .push() method

Tags: jquery, json, javascript-objects

I want to create javascript object using `.push()` Method and create `Key Value Pair`.
I have tried it, but it doesn't work.

```
$("input[name^=ang_nama]").each(function() {
   arr_nama.push($(this).attr('id'):$(this).val());
});
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to want this :

```
var arr_nama = [];
$("input[name^=ang_nama]").each(function() {
   var obj = {};
   obj[this.id] = $(this).val();
   arr_nama.push(obj);
});
```

A few observations :

- don't use `$(this).attr('id')` when you can use `this.id` !
- you have to initialize the array before you push to it
- you can't directly create an object literal with a dynamic property name, you must create the object first

Another cleaner solution would be

```
var arr_nama = $("input[name^=ang_nama]").map(function() {
   var obj = {};
   obj[this.id] = $(this).val();
   return obj;
}).get();
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/oyesoc/1/edit)**

Note that this creates an array. If what you wanted is a unique object, use this :

```
var arr_nama = {};
$("input[name^=ang_nama]").each(function() {
   arr_nama[this.id] = $(this).val();
});
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/oyesoc/2/edit)**

Comment: "don't use $(this).attr('id') when you can use this.id "  same for value :)

Comment: @roasted yes, but only because it's an `input`. For some elements it's not exactly the same behavior, that's why I'm reluctant to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var obj = {};
obj[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
arr_nama.push(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add curly braces while pushing

```
$("input[name^=ang_nama]").each(function() {
     arr_nama.push( { $(this).attr('id'):$(this).val() } );
});
```

Comment: No, you can't do this in JavaScript.